# CRM to SQL Server data migration -data missing issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm, etl

I have created an SSIS package for migrating data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM to SQL server.The SSIS package is working fine.But some data are missing from the table in SQL server after migration.What are the known possibilities to miss the data which is available in CRM and not in SQL Server?

Comment: Based on the information provided... it's anyone's guess. There isn't enough info here.

Comment: I have just mentioned the source as CRM and destination as SQL server table in SSIS packages.I didn't use any query to filter data.Still, some data is missing.Is this a known issue?

Comment: No it's not a known issue. Maybe the data arrived in the CRM after you loaded it. Are the source and target databases SQL Server? Are the source and target schemas identical (including nullability and foreign keys?)

Comment: The only known possibility is that you have made a mistake.   It's impossible to be more specific unless you provide more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments. The mistake is, there was a service timeout parameter in SSIS package which was set to 120. But I had to load a large amount of data from crm to sql server table. Somehow the timeout error was occured.But still it showed the status as succeeded.

It was little bit confusing. The timeout had been changed to a large value which was more than 120 .Hence the problem was solved. Since I am a beginner in these kind of activities, comments here helped me to identify the mistake I have made.